# If $C_{n}/b_{n}\longrightarrow 0$ and $C_{n}/\sqrt{n}\longrightarrow\infty$, show $(2n\log C_{n})/b_{n}^{2}\longrightarrow 1$.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Given $b_{n}=\sqrt{n\log n}$ for $n\geq 1$ and $C_{n}\geq 1$ are such that $C_{n}/b_{n}\longrightarrow 0$ and $C_{n}/\sqrt{n}\longrightarrow\infty$, I'd like to show that

$(1)$ $\dfrac{2n\log C_{n}}{b_{n}^{2}}\longrightarrow 1$

$(2)$ $\dfrac{nC_{n}^{2}}{b_{n}^{2}}\longrightarrow 0$.

For the first one, initially I wanted to apply L'Hopitcal's Rule, but the problem here is that $C_{n}$ is a function of $n$ and I don't know what the explicit formula of $C_{n}$ is, so we cannot take derivative. Thus we need to at least get rid of $C_{n}$, but I don't know how to proceed.

For the second, I know that $C_{n}^{2}/b_{n}^{2}\longrightarrow 0$, but we also have $n\longrightarrow\infty$, if I remember it correctly, we cannot have $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(a_{n}b_{n})=0$ if $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{n}=\infty$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_{n}=0$.

What should I do here?  perhaps I must have the formula of $C_{n}$?

Thank you!

Comment: Something is wrong here.  You say you want to prove
$$\frac{2\log C_n}{\log n} \to 1, \qquad \frac{C_n^2}{\log n} \to 0$$
but these cannot both hold simultaneously since $C_n^2 \geq \log C_n.$

Comment: @BrianMoehring Yes since this is part of a proof of something else, I just paraphrase the conclusion I want to make here. Perhaps I interpret the proof in a wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both conclusions are incorrect. Try $C_n = \sqrt{n} \cdot \root{4}\of{\log n}$.

Comment: Yes you are right. The thing I want to prove is part of a proof of other theorem, perhaps I interpret it wrong..